# ASP.NET MVC application with multiple LDAP servers

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, active-directory

We are using an ASP.NET MVC 3.0 web application using windows authentication. We have a primary Domain controller and multiple(right now two) backup servers for fail-over scenarios.

Do we need to handle the fail-over from primary LDAP server to secondary explicitly in our web-application by adding multiple membership providers for primary and secondary? Or is it possible to handle this fail-over transparently out-side the web application using a load-balancer?

In case we need to handle it from the web-application, can someone please refer some resource
on how to

1. Configure multiple membership-providers
2. Detect that primary LDAP server is down
3. Switch over to secondary LDAP server from primary
   LDAP server for authentication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be a non-issue if you point your connectionString to the domain instead of a particular server. AD is good at handling a DC going offline.